# How to croll this... ScrollView

Tags: android, view, scroll, scrollview

I try to force scroll ScrollView to some point.
I use Handler to ensure that data in scroll view already loaded and it is huge.

```
Handler handler1 = new Handler();
  handler1.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
       scrollView.smoothScrollTo(0, 1500);
    }
}, 1500);
```

But why any of `smoothScrollTo` or `scrollTo` do nothing?

Comment: This link might be useful for you.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14811032/scrollview-not-scrolling-at-all

Comment: @DobriKostadinov Not work.