# Keyboard and scrollviews

Tags: android, keyboard, scrollview, android-scrollview

I have an activity with a form. I put all views in a `ScrollView` because when the keyboard opens, I would scroll through the fields.

When the keyboard opens, the first field goes over the top of the `ScrollView` and becomes unreachable.

This is the layout:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/username"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:hint="Username"
        android:inputType="text|textEmailAddress"
        android:singleLine="true" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/password"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:hint="Password"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:singleLine="true" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/password1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:hint="@string/repeat_password"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:singleLine="true" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/gender" />

        <RadioGroup
            android:id="@+id/gender"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp">

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/male"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:checked="true"
                android:text="M" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/female"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="F" />
        </RadioGroup>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/age" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/age"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/education" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/education"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:onClick="salva"
        android:text="@string/save" />
</LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

This is the activity definition in the manifest:

```
<activity
        android:name=".activities.SignUpActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_sign_up">
</activity>
```

This is a screenshot. The username field is unreachable! (look at the scrollbar on the right)
[image: Screenshot]

Comment: android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustPan" add this in your manifest activity section

Comment: This way the view is not scrollable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution. The problem was this line:

```
android:layout_gravity="center"
```

I just removed it from the layout file. The manifest was correct.

Answer (score 1):

Use following in your App **Manifest**

```
 android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustPan"
```

For more details you can visit here

> http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html

Comment: This way the keyboard covers the EditText on the bottom

Comment: @fran okay . understand . please update your xml .http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14811032/scrollview-not-scrolling-at-all

Answer (score 0):

In your activity manifest entry add this:

`android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustPan"`.

Comment: This way the view is not scrollable