# ScrollView is not scrolling in android

Tags: android, android-scrollview

Hi i am new for android and I cant understand why this is happening. I am unable to scroll my scrollview. It has a textView , an imageview and few linear layouts inside of it and my code is below

can some one  help me please

### code:-

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:theme="@style/Content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="15dp"
        android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:scrollbars="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/enter_basicinformation_title" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="3">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/edit_text_margin_top"
                android:layout_weight="2">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">

                    <fr.ganfra.materialspinner.MaterialSpinner
                        android:id="@+id/spinState"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        app:ms_arrowColor="@color/text_hint_color"
                        app:ms_arrowSize="16dp"
                        app:ms_floatingLabelColor="@color/text_hint_color"
                        app:ms_floatingLabelText="@string/sir_name_title"
                        app:ms_highlightColor="@color/colorAccent"
                        app:ms_hint="@string/sir_name_title"
                        app:ms_multiline="true" />

                </RelativeLayout>

            </LinearLayout>

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:theme="@style/TextFieldInputLayout">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/username_id"
                    style="@style/MaterialDesignEditTextStyle"
                    android:drawablePadding="10dp"
                    android:hint="@string/username_hint"
                    android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                    android:inputType="textPersonName"
                    android:nextFocusDown="@+id/lastname_id" />

            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/edit_text_margin_top"
            android:theme="@style/TextFieldInputLayout">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/lastname_id"
                style="@style/MaterialDesignEditTextStyle"
                android:drawablePadding="10dp"
                android:hint="@string/last_name_hint"
                android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                android:inputType="textPersonName"
                android:nextFocusDown="@+id/email_id" />

        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/edit_text_margin_top"
            android:theme="@style/TextFieldInputLayout">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/email_id"
                style="@style/MaterialDesignEditTextStyle"
                android:drawablePadding="10dp"
                android:hint="@string/email_id_hint"
                android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                android:inputType="textPersonName"
                android:nextFocusDown="@+id/re_email_id" />

        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/edit_text_margin_top"
            android:theme="@style/TextFieldInputLayout">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/re_email_id"
                style="@style/MaterialDesignEditTextStyle"
                android:drawablePadding="10dp"
                android:hint="@string/re_email_id_hint"
                android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                android:inputType="textPersonName" />

        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/edit_text_margin_top"
            android:theme="@style/TextFieldInputLayout">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/password_id"
                style="@style/MaterialDesignEditTextStyle"
                android:drawablePadding="10dp"
                android:hint="@string/password_hint"
                android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                android:inputType="textPersonName"
                android:nextFocusDown="@+id/re_password_id" />

        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/TextFieldInputLayout">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/re_password_id"
                style="@style/MaterialDesignEditTextStyle"
                android:drawablePadding="10dp"
                android:hint="@string/re_reenter_password_hint"
                android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                android:inputType="textPersonName" />

        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/register_button_id"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:paddingLeft="15dp"
            android:paddingRight="15dp"
            android:text="@string/register_title"
            android:theme="@style/greenColorButton" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
            android:text="@string/existing_user_title" />

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

### screen:-

[image]

Comment: can you post a screenshot, too?

Comment: does you layout has enough views to scroll?

Comment: ScrollView should be parent

Comment: @AbhiRam try that:
Remove  android:scrollbars="vertical" from LinearLayout and add `android:fillViewPort="true"` to the scrollView

Comment: @AbhiRam I would also suggest you NOT to use the `ScrollView` as root of the layout, it's a bad practice

Comment: can u post working code please

Comment: what do you mean by 'working code' ?

Comment: i mean can u edit my code please send workable code

Answer (score 0):

```
// Make parent layout scroll and put linear layout inside .
```

```html
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:scrollbars="vertical" >

    ... 
    ...
</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: i had the same problem .i solved it after make scroll view as parent..try it and let me know..

Comment: i am trying wait i will tellu result

Comment: no this is not working i updated my code with ur code

Comment: @AbhiRam pls send us a screenshot of your app, otherwise it's difficult to help you

Comment: android:fillViewport="true" add this in scrool view.

Comment: please see this link ..may this help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14811032/scrollview-not-scrolling-at-all

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
I have removed the @style/content, add it later again. The rest is modified like i have told you in the comments

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ScrollView 
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="15dp"
            android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/enter_basicinformation_title" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="3">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/edit_text_margin_top"
                    android:layout_weight="2">

                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent">

                        <fr.ganfra.materialspinner.MaterialSpinner
                            android:id="@+id/spinState"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                            app:ms_arrowColor="@color/text_hint_color"
                            app:ms_arrowSize="16dp"
                            app:ms_floatingLabelColor="@color/text_hint_color"
                            app:ms_floatingLabelText="@string/sir_name_title"
                            app:ms_highlightColor="@color/colorAccent"
                            app:ms_hint="@string/sir_name_title"
                            app:ms_multiline="true" />

                    </RelativeLayout>

                </LinearLayout>

                <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:theme="@style/TextFieldInputLayout">

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/username_id"
                        style="@style/MaterialDesignEditTextStyle"
                        android:drawablePadding="10dp"
                        android:hint="@string/username_hint"
                        android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                        android:inputType="textPersonName"
                        android:nextFocusDown="@+id/lastname_id" />

                </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

            </LinearLayout>

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/edit_text_margin_top"
                android:theme="@style/TextFieldInputLayout">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/lastname_id"
                    style="@style/MaterialDesignEditTextStyle"
                    android:drawablePadding="10dp"
                    android:hint="@string/last_name_hint"
                    android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                    android:inputType="textPersonName"
                    android:nextFocusDown="@+id/email_id" />

            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/edit_text_margin_top"
                android:theme="@style/TextFieldInputLayout">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/email_id"
                    style="@style/MaterialDesignEditTextStyle"
                    android:drawablePadding="10dp"
                    android:hint="@string/email_id_hint"
                    android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                    android:inputType="textPersonName"
                    android:nextFocusDown="@+id/re_email_id" />

            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/edit_text_margin_top"
                android:theme="@style/TextFieldInputLayout">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/re_email_id"
                    style="@style/MaterialDesignEditTextStyle"
                    android:drawablePadding="10dp"
                    android:hint="@string/re_email_id_hint"
                    android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                    android:inputType="textPersonName" />

            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/edit_text_margin_top"
                android:theme="@style/TextFieldInputLayout">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/password_id"
                    style="@style/MaterialDesignEditTextStyle"
                    android:drawablePadding="10dp"
                    android:hint="@string/password_hint"
                    android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                    android:inputType="textPersonName"
                    android:nextFocusDown="@+id/re_password_id" />

            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:theme="@style/TextFieldInputLayout">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/re_password_id"
                    style="@style/MaterialDesignEditTextStyle"
                    android:drawablePadding="10dp"
                    android:hint="@string/re_reenter_password_hint"
                    android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                    android:inputType="textPersonName" />

            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/register_button_id"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:paddingLeft="15dp"
                android:paddingRight="15dp"
                android:text="@string/register_title"
                android:theme="@style/greenColorButton" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
                android:text="@string/existing_user_title" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>
</FrameLayout>
```